# Allow user to enter millisecond in datetime picker in jsf/adf form

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I want to allow user to select millisecond also on datepicker. I have tried differant articles but it allows me to only enter dd-mm-ss and timezone.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one solution: contact the developers of the component and ask them to add it.